# Expression in SSRS based on two different values from different data sources

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to make an expression in MS SQL Server Report Builder based on two different values from different data sources. The two data sources / dataset is like the following example:

**Datasets 1 (from data source 1)**

```
Name                Country StartDate        EndDate   
-----------------------------------
Clientname 1        NL      01-01-2018       31-12-2018
Clientname 2        US      01-03-2018       28-2-2019
Clientname 3        UK      01-08-2018       31-7-2019
```

**Datasets 2 (from data source 2)**

```
Name            Date         Weight
-----------------------------------
Clientname 1        28-11-2017   20000
Clientname 1        4-1-2018     20000
Clientname 1        8-1-2018     44000
Clientname 2        8-7-2018     10000
Clientname 2        8-11-2018    20000
Clientname 3        4-8-2018     80000
Clientname 3        8-9-2018     40000
Clientname 3        8-10-2018    20000
Clientname 3        8-11-2018    40000
```

The result of the expression must be the sum of the values (weight) from dataset 2 which fall between the Start and End date of dataset 1.

For example for Clientname1, 28-11-2017 is out of the start and enddate and should not be included in the som. The result of Clientname should therefore total 64000 *(20000 from 4-1-2018 + 44000 from 8-1-2018)*.

Hopefully you can help me with this, thanks in advance!

Comment: What are the sources of these data sets? If it is SQL I can help you get code to put that result into Dataset1

Comment: These are both the same Microsoft Sql server "VM-SQL01"

Comment: Are they views / stored procs / or SQL

Comment: If the result comes in 1 dataset, this would also be a solution. What do you mean with views / stored proces / or SQL?

Comment: from report data, open Dataset properties of each data set. It initially opens on Query. What is the query type? If text, please paste the text in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Change dataset1 to the following:

```
select a.*
    ,isnull(c.SUMofWeight ,0)
from [However you created DS1] a
outer apply(select SUM(Weight) as SUMofWeight 
            from [however you create DS2] b 
            where b.date between a.startdate and a.enddate 
                AND a.Name = b.Name) c
```

This will add the column you are looking for to data set 1.

Comment: When I use this code I get the message that the DS2 is not valid

Is there no an easier way to do this with an expression directly in the table?

Comment: This is how you solve your problem, someone else can give you the band aid solution. You realize you need to replace whatever is inside the brackets with a table name, a view, or a CTE right?